# Getting checkins from friends

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm trying to get the checkins from my friends.

If I try it with the Graph Explorer provided by Facebook it works most of the time.

As soon as I'm trying the same call through my PHP script, the checkins are never returned.

Has anyone an idea why thats the case?

```
/me?fields=id,friends.fields(checkins.fields(place,coordinates),first_name,last_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you asked the user for these permissions in your app: `user_status` and `friends_status` ?

It might be possible that you have not selected your app in the Graph API Explorer and used some other app with these permissions, such that you see the results there.